# How to preserve directory structure but delete some of its contents... using bash

Tags: bash

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
workspace  
|-- cleanup.sh  
|-- node_modules  
|-- job1  
|---- testResults   
|---- some other folder  
|---- some file  
|---- some file  
|-- job2  
|---- ...
```

How can I:

- Not delete cleanup.sh, node_modules and the sub-folder job*/testResults
- Delete "some file" and "some other folder"

In other words: keep the directory structure as-is but delete everything except the node_module folder (in its entirety), the testResults sub-folder and the cleanup.sh script itself.

My not working script thus far...

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in ./*
do
   if [ -d $i ]
   then
      if [ "$i" = "./workspace/node_modules" ]
      then
         echo "Inside node_modules. Skipping."
      else
         echo "Inside directory: $i. Deleting and preserving only testResults."
         rm !(testResults|"cleanup.sh")
      fi
   fi
done
```

Comment: If you have `shopt -s extglob` is there any reason you can't just do `rm -rf !(cleanup.sh|node_modules|job1/testResults)`? This could also keep `job2/testResults`, if you replaced `job1` with `*`, `**`, or `job*` or something, I guess.

Comment: I've changed the rm line to what you suggested but it deletes nothing... hm.

Comment: If you echo the above command does it expand ? `echo rm -rf !(cleanup.sh|node_modules|job1/testResults)` . In my tests , even with echo i can see that bash is expanding all the files and i can see that files inside !(..) are missing.

Comment: It does not. Where are you calling it from? from cleanup.sh?

Comment: No , directly from terminal.... and works fine (after stepping in to the corresponding directory with `cd`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event testResults is a directory, I believe a slightly modified version of the solution by @hek2mgl is required:

```
find workspace/job* -mindepth 1 ! -path '*testResults*' -exec rm -r {} +
```

Note that I have started one level above as per your description.

You can test what the `rm` will do by using ls instead:

```
find workspace/job* -mindepth 1 ! -path '*testResults*' -exec ls -lad {} +
```

@hek2mgl: I would have commented on yours but I don't have the reputation required.

Comment: This worked: `find workspace/job* -mindepth 1 ! -path '*testResults*' ! -path '*node_modules*' -exec rm -r {} +`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu-find then this command will do the job:

```
find /path/to/workspace/ -mindepth 1 -regextype posix-extended \
-not -iregex '.*/(testResults(/.*)?|node_modules(/.*)?|cleanup\.sh)$' -delete
```